# npm ERR! missing script: start error when pushing phoenix project to dokku

Tags: npm, phoenix-framework, dokku

I'm trying to setup a new clean phoenix framework project (v 1.1.1) on dokku on digitalocean.

I first got this error message:

```
=====> phoenix container output:
       npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-71-generic
       npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
       npm ERR! node v5.1.1
       npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
       npm ERR! missing script: start
       npm ERR!
       npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
       npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
       npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
       npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
=====> end phoenix container output
```

but then I figured/googled out that I need to add `"scripts": { "start":` to package.json
like so:

```
{
  "repository": {
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "^6.0.0",
    "brunch": "^2.0.0",
    "clean-css-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "css-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "javascript-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "uglify-js-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
}
```

but I don't understand where/to what file I should point the node start to? Has anyone else had this same error message?

Comment: Err. was happening because I was using the wrong buildpack. See more here: https://gist.github.com/henrik/c70e32544e09c1a79841

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you following a guide or tutorial? It looks to me like you are wanting to start a node container, not elixir/phoenix?

Anyways I just recently set up a dokku on digitalocean for Phoenix. I did it following this guide: http://blog.praveenperera.com/deploying-phoenix-applications-using-dokku/

Let me know if you get stuck or need some help :)

Comment: I was following some notes by Henrik: https://gist.github.com/henrik/c70e32544e09c1a79841  Reading the comments below I misunderstood and thought step 2 & step 3 weren't necessary, but of course they were. :) And now it's working! :D

Comment: Thank you for offering help!